# EditText NullPointerException - Event Handling

Tags: android

I have a button that adds an object to a List View. I want to implement it seperately in a `Handler` class, so I call `new Handler(this)` inside `.setOnClickListener`.

This is how I call the `Handler` in `MainActivity` class:

```
Button button_createTask = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_createTask);
button_createTask.setOnClickListener(new Handler(this));
```

This is inside of `Handler` class:

```
public class Handler implements View.OnClickListener {

private MainActivity mainActivity;

public Handler(MainActivity mainActivity) {
    this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    // Read task data
    EditText etTaskName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_taskName);
    EditText etTaskDate = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_taskDate);
    EditText etTaskDescription = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_taskDescription);

    // Save task name
    String taskName = etTaskName.getText().toString();

    //...
}
```

My app crashes with the following error, pointing to line `String taskName = etTaskName.getText().toString();`:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 10287
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.myapplication.Handler.onClick(Handler.java:37)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Releavant layout:

[image: Here is the relevant layout.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `MainActivity`, the button's view is being selected and sent over to the handler.

If we want to find other elements by their id, we need a bigger view, in this case the parent view suffices.

Change the handler class like so:

```
public void onClick(View buttonView) {
    View view = (View) buttonView.getParent();
    EditText etTaskName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_taskName);
    // ...
```